# Need to edit code to get all strings between two strings (gets only first one)

Tags: vb.net

I got code for getting the first match. But the code does not get all matches. Can someone explain me how to do that? :)

```
 Dim Start As Integer = 0, [End] As Integer = 0
        If content.Contains(startString) AndAlso content.Contains(endString) Then
            Start = content.IndexOf(startString, 0) + startString.Length
            [End] = content.IndexOf(endString, Start)
            Return content.Substring(Start, [End] - Start)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
```

This works beautifuly for the first string and is easy to use. Just need to make it get a string array that i will use later (there are aprox. 5-10 strings that are always present between startString and endString).

Update:

```
    Dim Searchstring As String
    Searchstring = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim SearchStringPlus = Regex.Replace(Searchstring, "\s+", "+")
    Dim SearchHTML As String
    Dim WebClient1 As New Net.WebClient
    SearchHTML = WebClient1.DownloadString("https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" & SearchStringPlus & "&s=tt")
    Dim SearchIndex As String = "<td class=""primary_photo""> <a href=""/title/tt"
    Dim iSearch As System.IO.StreamWriter
    iSearch = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("iSearch.txt", False)
    iSearch.WriteLine(SearchHTML)
    iSearch.Close()
    Dim SearchHTMLR As String
    SearchHTMLR = IO.File.ReadAllLines("iSearch.txt").FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains(SearchIndex))
    Dim titles As String
    titles = GetStringBetween(SearchHTMLR, "<a href=""/title/", "/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1")
    MessageBox.Show(titles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the Substring method.

Vb.Net

```
  Private Function GetStringBetween(ByVal str As String, ByVal startStr As String, ByVal endStr As String) As String
        Return str.Substring(startStr.Length, str.Length - (startStr.Length + endStr.Length))
    End Function
```

C#

```
 private string GetStringBetween(string str, string start, string end)
 {
     return str.Substring(start.Length, str.Length - (start.Length + end.Length));
 }
```

Comment: What is start.Lenght? Thanks btw.

Comment: str = SearchHTMLR, startStr = "<a href=""/title/" and endStr = "/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1"

Comment: It returns a slightly cropped full SearchHTMLR but nothing related to startStr and endStr unfortunately. I doped the full code.

Comment: I thought you wanted the text between startStr and endStr?

Comment: Yes but it did not return it as such. Solved it nvm :) Thanks anyways.